# Many active states simultaneously with ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

What would you like to be able to do for example is:

I have an active state 'order.detail' in shell, in these details would provide a link in each product line that leads to 'product.detail' state that is also a state that can be displayed in the shell.

But this link should display the state ' product.detail' as a frame in a dialog without changing the current location and maintain active state in the shell intact.

Also the 'product.detail' state, to be used as a main view of the shell, and to allow their reuse, your template should be wrapped by 'div' template of dialogue.

What I mean is, allow consult the details of something without leaving the current screen, and do so using the same existing details screen, or simply allow the 'Drill down' by related data with existing views.

Answer (score 1):

## Sharing state in AngularJS

One of the great things about Angular is that's it quite easy to keep track of state via [providers](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers).

For example consider one *index* view containing a paged grid table with many filter options. Clicking on one of the entries will take you to *details* view of the entry. When the user goes back from the *details* to the *index* he/she will expect that the UI state of the grid will be exactly the way they left it: same page, same sort by, same filters applied, same everything. With traditional techniques you would have to fallback on cookies, query params and/or server side state(less) magic, which all feels (and actually is) very cumbersome and error prone.

Provider values are *singletons* in the world of Angular, so when we inject the instance in one of the controllers, it will always be the same instance. Controllers on the other hand will be recreated each time one is requested.

### Example

Register an empty object to keep track of controllers:

```
myApp.value('formState', {});
```

Create a controller, inject the provider value and expose it on the scope:

```
myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope, formState) {
  $scope.formState = formState;
});
```

Hook any property of the provider value to input elements via the *ng-model* directive.

```
<input type="text" ngModel="formState.searchFilter"/>
```

Now every time the user will leave and re-enters this view the state of the UI is kept intact. You can add as many data to the state as you see fit and maybe even share it among multiple controllers if needed.

### Provider types

There are different ways to create provider values: factory, service, value, constant and provider. If you want more control over the state, eg state management, you could use one of the other options. More info can be found [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers).

### To dialog or not to dialog

In traditional websites displaying the details in a dialog was a "cheap" trick to keep track of the state in the background. Of course this is still an option with Angular, but there's no need for it. From the UX view, dialogs are *"not done"* and should be *avoided if possible*, but it also introduces pains in the areas of *responsiveness* and *printing*.

### Plunker examples

Some code examples sharing state among controllers/views.

- http://plnkr.co/edit/MwJrk5?p=preview
- http://plnkr.co/edit/bNJtOP?p=preview

Comment: Yes I know the capacity of providers, I use an advanced form of these states to maintain a dictionary of states of cache in each view it has to persisitir unchanged. This is not the case, and the fact that a dialogue is just one example. The whole question boils down to my last paragraph, a common concept in business application known as 'Drill down'. Make it possible to obtain two active states at the same time one without changing the other(specifically for ui-router in use to maintain a complex state machine)